# Multiple iFrames on site, all resize to a default height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm sorry if this question has been already answered, but can't narrow down or ask the question right.
Here goes, I have a client's website that has three embedded iFrames,the website is for Holiday accommodation and uses a Calendar, Booking Enquiry and the floorplans, all come from different vendors.
The problem is they all have different widths and height.

The width in most instances is set to 100% that's fine, but the height is where the problem is, even if I try to set the height to what I want it, it defaults back to a set size.

The default size is 309px and is in two css files needed for the site in general.

Is there a little snippet of code that could over ride that size set in the CSS?
The site in question is here: http://aalen.com.au/aalen1-pims.php
The main area of concern is the Floor plans, they just end up in a smaller iFrame and doesn't show off the potential of those plans. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page, I can only see one CSS file affecting your `iframe`, app.css, there are other css files, but none of them change the height of the element.

I assume you're referring to this code from your website.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="400" scrolling="no" src="http://pl.an/aalen-1/embed" width="100%"></iframe>
```

It looks like you're setting the height in two places, once in app.css with the code:

```
iframe{
    height:390px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You are also setting the `iframe` height with the `height` attribute as seen in the first code example. Try removing the `height="400"` attribute from your `iframe` tag and only have the height in the app.css file.

In future you can try using the [Firefox developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools) or [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to manipulate the CSS on the page while it is open, in order to see what you need to change, and how it will affect the rest of the content on your page.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for looking and being so quick to respond, I didn't put a lot of detail into the first question, thinking it might have been answered before and after all these years of using Firebug I realised you can actually change the code ..derr. So back to this problem, yes that app.css size is for a smaller iFrame up the page, and over rides that floorplan size, I have tried it with and without the 400 height. If I was to set the css to a higher number, the smaller iFrames up the page have this huge amount of space underneath them, hope this is making sense??

Comment: It's because your `iframe` css rule is matching with all the iframes on the page, not just the one you want to change, so when you modify the height of that iframe, all of them change. You can change that by adding an `id` tag to the floorplan iframe, and then adjust the height with that.